# Power series of a function with multiplication

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I don't understand what happens during series multiplication and substitution. It doesn't seem to make sense. Shouldn't it just be $\large(x^{n})^{n}$?

[image]

[image]

Comment: See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Comment: Please post questions as text and LaTeX instead of just a big image.  As it is, the question is unsearchable and a strain to read.

Answer (score 1):

The comment by Cortizol explains how to multiply two power series together. However, the solution above is dull as dishwater. Notice that $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x}$. Thus,

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots)=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\ldots$$

which can be written as $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)x^{i}$.

Comment: I think Im missing something here. Why are you finding the derivative?

Comment: @user1730308, differentiating is just a way of reducing the problem to an expression whose power series is already known.